# RDS cals after a 2012r2 to 2019 in place upgrade

Tags: rds

I have a question, what happens with the RDS cals after an in-place upgrade from 2012r2 to 2019? We have a single RDS 2012 r2 server with the RD Connection broker, RD Session Host, RD Licensing, and RD Web Access roles installed. Three quarters of our RDS user cals are 2019, installed on this 2012 server. They were the only version available when we purchased the cals in 2019, open licensing. I installed them on the server and they show up as 2012 per user cals. After the upgrade will it automatically recognize them as 2019 cals, or will I need to reinstall the cals using the same information I originally used? Any help would be appreciated, thanks...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/rds-client-access-license#rds-cal-version-compatibility

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the rdp role before you do the in place upgrade. So you would just re install your licences after the upgrade is successful and it would be like setting up rdp for the first time.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).